# Is this argument about sharp and blunt lightning rod right?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, electrical-resistance, lightning

Actually I came to know that sharp lightning rods are not sensitive to the weak electric field comparing to blunt lightning rods. Resistance will resist the formation of field on the rod. So, we know that resistance would decrease if area increases. So a blunt one will have more area compared to sharp ones thus offered way less resistance. But is this the formal way of proving this? Also is there any other way to prove this? If yes, pls mention it.

Comment: Where do you have this info from? Could it be this paper https://doi.org/10.1175/1520-0450(2003)042<0984:TCFUBL>2.0.CO;2 ? Providing this would make it more clear what exactly you are referring to

Comment: I actually referred it. There's mostly theoretical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, sharpening the tip of a high-voltage probe has the effect of greatly magnifying the *electric field gradient* at the tip, making it easier for charges to flow off or onto the tip. So, to help the lightning find and strike the tip instead of the building to which it is attached, the tip is made sharp and also positioned high enough off the top of the building so as to serve as the "sole representative" of the building from an electrostatic viewpoint.

Comment: As mentioned by University physics with modern physics, sharper ones can obtain charge only if there's high enough electric field, but lower can obtain charge even if it's low. Also this site doi.org/10.1175/1520-0450(2003)042<0984:TCFUBL>2.0.CO;2 mention it too. Experimental results has also biased towards blunter ones.